# Inflated binomial CI due to non-zero bad quality data fraction?

Tags: confidence-interval, binomial-distribution, measurement-error

Let's say you have some dataset of observations which are either 0 or 1, and you want to estimate the mean and standard deviation / CI. This is straightforward to do. If the number of observations is N and the fraction of successes is f, then

mean = $f$

$\sigma = (f(1-f)/N)^{1/2}$

95% CI: $[f - 2\sigma, f + 2\sigma]$

assuming we have sufficient volume of data and $f$ isn't too near 0 or 1.

But now let's say that you know that some non-zero fraction $f_{bad}$ of those observations are bad, as in the 1 or 0 of that datapoint is not to be trusted. In a perfect world, the datapoint would be thrown out or re-measured, but we do not know which specific observations are bad, just the aggregate fraction.

Is there a way to inflate the size of the CI bands to account for this bad data?  Obviously if $f_{bad}=0$ then no adjustment is needed, while $f_{bad}=1$ means all data is bad and the CI should probably be something like [0,1], or perhaps just undefined. I don't think it's possible to adjust the point estimate f, at least without strong priors.

For the particular situation I'm examining, the size of the datasets are $N\sim1000$ with $f_{bad}\sim0.1$.

Comment: Can we assume that a bad data point is 0 or 1 with a probability of 50%, or is that unknown as well?

Comment: Good question. I think we should assume the underlying probability of a bad data point is completely unknown, flat prior between 0 and 1